# upgrade iphone 4 to latest iOS as 9 or 10

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to upgrade iPhone 4 iOS to 9 or 10 using jail break approach?

Main purpose to install apps which require latest iOS. So is there any method even through security bypass?

Rather throwing the older phone any possibility by experimenting?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [iOS Support Matrix](http://iossupportmatrix.com), you will see that the latest version of iOS that supports the iPhone 4 is iOS 7.

You can't upgrade to a version of iOS greater than that - so iOS 8, 9, 10, 11, or the upcoming 12, are all out of reach for that phone.

Comment: will it be possible through jail break or any other non genuine way?

Comment: I would be very surprised if it worked. Usually, later phones have more resources (RAM, CPU, etc.) that make the later OSs run more slowly on earlier phones, if they will run at all

Comment: I seen such comments on some you tube video also. But in first place is it possible to install later version even though it is resource consuming? Reason I ask this question is to get apps like FB or Viber. Which is not possible install on iphone 4.

Comment: All I can say is - try it. I have never tried this, so I can’t say definitively whether it would work or not.

Comment: iPhone 4 is built on 32-bit hardware. Current iOS & all apps are 64-bit. There is no way past this.

Comment: I looked into that - only iOS 11 (and 12, of course) is purely 64-bit. Previous versions (up to 10) could run on some 32-bit software, but the iPhone 4 is too old for any version after iOS 7

Comment: You probably would need a lot more than its meagre 512MB RAM too.

Comment: A point I made earlier (the "RAM, CPU" comment)